# PostgreSQL SQL import fails with error as schema not found

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to import an SQL file as part of the database through PGAdmin3 but I am getting error as the schema not found. But when I try to select the namespace it list that schema.
Below is the output from the DB

```
test=# select nspname from pg_catalog.pg_namespace;
      nspname
--------------------
 pg_catalog
 pg_toast
 public
 pg_temp_1
 pg_toast_temp_1
 information_schema
 testschema
(7 rows)
```

Below is the sql commands which I am trying to run from script

```
CREATE TABLE TestSchema.Emp (
                lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                firstname VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                empid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
};

ERROR:  schema "testschema" does not exist
********** Error **********

ERROR: schema "testschema" does not exist
SQL state: 3F000
```

Any thoughts why this error is coming.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the same database both times?

Comment: When the pgadmin3 launch it ask me database which I provide it. But I don't know if it use "" for the DB Name as I have another DB which is created using quoted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
CREATE TABLE TestSchema.Emp (
                lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                firstname VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                empid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
}; -- Put ) instead of }
```

Normally it does not work

Comment: My bad I will fix the same and take a look again as I was learning PG programming but later didn't get much time to look into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
CREATE TABLE TestSchema.Emp (
```

By

```
CREATE TABLE testschema.Emp (
```

Comment: No, Postgres is not case-sensitive if the identifiers are not quoted.